# Is it unprofessional to quit a freelance gig early

Tags: employment

What I'm trying to think about is whether or not it makes more sense to not take a freelance job, knowing that it's a bad job for you (due to pay, hours, activities) except that you're getting paid, because if you took it you'd be unhappy and would want to quit as soon as a full-time job came through.

Comment: There is a freelancing stackexchange site, you may get a better answer there.

Comment: Would that mean breaking terms of the contract? If the contract said you'd work for 2 more weeks would you be saying, "I'm not doing that! I quit today and start a new job tomorrow," or would you work through the last 2 weeks before going to another job?

Comment: @JBKing If I got a job offer, I would do what I would do for any company - give 2 weeks notice.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere There wouldn't be an actual contract, just a "We think this project will take up to 2 months."

Comment: It's helpful if people have suggestions for improving the question. I don't know if it really works on this SE site, so giving tips or redirects (like Wandering Dev Manager) is helpful.

Comment: Even though it's opinionated (as most Q's here are), if you put some more thought into this and put some more effort into presentation of the topic it might be better received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it unprofessional? Yes it is, you're client will not be impressed.

Having said that, it's also reasonably common. People need money and take what they can to cover expenses in the interim. That's just practical. I have taken many jobs I had no intention of making a career out of, and jumped ship as soon as I saw a better position elsewhere.

It's one of the risks people take when hiring freelancers.

Comment: There are many scenarios in which it could be made more professional.  "I'd like to continue working for you, but I've just learned that there was a death in the family.  In light of this, I don't feel comfortable working right now, but I will be in touch as soon as I feel ready."

Comment: @Makoto there is nothing professional about telling lies, not in the countries I have worked in anyway, perhaps where you come from

Comment: I've merely highlighted a valid scenario in which one may need to withdraw from a freelance gig.  I personally don't condone lying either, and of course, it's not a good thing to suddenly withdraw from agreed work.  But, these things do happen.

Comment: of course they happen, I said that in my answer, but you can't twist it into being professional, because it isn't. The OP is not talking about an out of the blue, unavoidable issue.

Comment: Even in an emergency, wzlking out is unprofessional. The professional response would be to subcontract the job, if you can't complete it. At a loss if necessary.  Part of why contractors charge more is so they can afford to do that.

Comment: @Makato Oh, no. Lying about a death in the family is tempting fate.

Answer (score 4):

It is professional to enter into a contract with the intent of fulfilling the contract. If you don't have that intent then it is unprofessional. You may have your reasons to do something unprofessional, but it is still unprofessional. Depending on how it is perceived when you leave early, it may or may not harm your reputation.

During the contract, things can happen. Both you and the company hiring you may decide that you are not the right person for the job, or that it isn't the right job for the person. Or the project is cancelled and so on. If your contract says that you can leave early and/or they can dismiss you early, then that's the risk that both sides take. You may be out of a job and out of money after 17 days, or they may be out of a person doing the job. That's life. If you do it for good reasons related to that job, it is professional. Doing it because you got a better offer I would see as unprofessional. Again, you may do unprofessional things for enough money.

During the contract, personal things can happen. If you leave, that may be unprofessional, but you may have a good reason. An employer will likely understand why you are doing it; they will still be annoyed, it is still unprofessional, but sometimes that can't be helped. You are not a machine.

But most importantly: You should NEVER enter a contract with the intent of not fulfilling it.